# Union different tables with differents columns and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

My problem is that I have 4 differents SELECT with

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS regular
WHERE experience = 1 AND bl = 1

SELECT COUNT (*) AS rptmm
WHERE experience = 1 AND bl = 0

SELECT COUNT (*) AS new
WHERE experience = 0 AND bl = 0

SELECT COUNT (*) AS rptss
WHERE experience = 0 AND bl = 1
```

I want that the results appear together whith the respective names like:

```
regular rptmm  new  rptss
  10      5     2     6
```

Comment: is each query against the same table?

Comment: Where are your `FROM` parts to these queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Firstly, I'd suggest not to use Count(*)***. There are many answers on this site explaining why so I am not going to repeat it.

Instead, I'd suggest you to use a query like this:

```
SELECT     (SELECT COUNT (tab.someColumnName)
           FROM TableName tab
           WHERE tab.experience = 1 AND tab.bl = 1) AS 'Regular',

           (SELECT COUNT (tab.someColumnName)
           FROM TableName tab               
           WHERE tab.experience = 1 AND tab.bl = 0) AS 'rptmm',

           (SELECT COUNT (tab.someColumnName)
           FROM TableName tab
           WHERE tab.experience = 0 AND tab.bl = 0) AS 'New',

           (SELECT COUNT (tab.someColumnName)
           FROM TableName tab
           WHERE tab.experience = 0 AND tab.bl = 1) AS 'rptss'
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @RandallSandoval Glad to help!! Please do read the edited answer where contains some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just put UNION ALL between your four statements you will get four rows with each count on its own row.  However, you will lose the column name.  You could also use join to get one row with four columnes.  Just put the keyword join between each sql statement.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS regular
WHERE experience = 1 AND bl = 1
JOIN
SELECT COUNT (*) AS rptmm
WHERE experience = 1 AND bl = 0
JOIN
SELECT COUNT (*) AS new
WHERE experience = 0 AND bl = 0
JOIN
SELECT COUNT (*) AS rptss
WHERE experience = 0 AND bl = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table to hold all of this data for you: Replace Name1, Name2, Name3,Name4 with whatever you want to call them. These will be the column headers.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
                        NAME1 INT
                       ,NAME2 INT
                       ,NAME3 INT
                       ,NAME4 INT
            )

INSERT INTO #Temp
(NAME1)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS regular
WHERE experience = 1 AND bl = 1

INSERT INTO #Temp
(NAME2)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS regular
WHERE experience = 1 AND bl = 0

INSERT INTO #Temp
(NAME3)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS regular
WHERE experience = 0 AND bl = 0

INSERT INTO #Temp
(NAME4)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS regular
WHERE experience = 0 AND bl = 1*

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```